# Can I use SQL Server Session State with sessions that contain DataTables?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I have inherited an ASP.NET 3.5 application that relies heavily on sessions and storing DataTables within them (I know - bad, bad, bad).  The application pool on the remote shared hosting service indicated that memory is at full capacity and as a result customers are losing their shopping carts because of dropped sessions.

Ultimately the goal is to rewrite this code, but for the time being I would like to stabilize the site the best I can.  The host has recommended I use SQL Server Session State instead of in-proc.  I have no experience with this, so I'm hoping it's as simple as running the .sql against the database to configure SQL Server and updating the web.config.

Any ideas?  Thanks.

Comment: Seems like a resonable quick fix.  The only other option I can see for a quickie is to make the data tables smaller.  Are there any columns/rows in those data tables that don't ever get used?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The docs say only that the session data has to be serializable.  AFAIK DataTables are not serializable, unless you do it yourself, which is probably not going to work.

Comment: No comment on why the downvote?  Which technical detail is wrong?

Comment: I'm curious to know myself.  Obviously as I'm the thread starter :)

Comment: FWIW, when I say "do it yourself", it appears you must write some kind of serializing code, which runs it out to XML or anything else that you can unserialize.

Comment: Ken, since nobody else wants to chime in and simply downvote you, I will accept your answer.  I will look into other options since additional coding effort is not optimal at this time.  Thanks.